# How do I search for a cell by its text, then display the value of the cell to its right in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, match, vlookup

So, I need a formula that searches for a cell in a specific row (or one of multiple rows) by its text, then displays the value of the cell to the right of it. I don't even know how to begin to do this one...

Here's an example of this:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1szzz.png) is an example of a list of phrases with associated numbers that'll come up later in the sheet.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBRB8.png) I want a formula that searches for instances of the word in the cell to its left appearing in Column A, and then display the value of the cell to the searched cell's right. Note that I'm only searching for phrases that come up once...

[...and this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veUsz.png) is what I'd want the result to be.

(I'm on mobile, if that affects anything.)

EDIT: Also I've realized, unlike in the image the formula would actually be searching for a phrase TWO cells to its left instead of one, sorry!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 I already provided an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in H26:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(G26:G, A:B, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: This worked really well! When I combed it with an answer I got to a previous question, it made autofill really easy too: `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-2)), {(N:O);(S:T)}, 2, 0)))` Thanks a lot! :D